# Click button with dataset, and the div with the same dataset will show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button with data-id="1" and i have a div with data-id="1", i want to do when press the button so its get the data-id of the button and the div with the same data-id will show up.

i have this code: jsfiddle.net/mmqjs5zs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.row2').click(function(e) {
    $('.actionsDiv[data-id="' + $(this).data('id') + '"]').show();    
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/mmqjs5zs/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can give the id in the .row2 click function to an attribute selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.actionsDiv').hide();

    $('.row2').click(function(){
        var id = this.dataset.id;
        $('.actionsDiv[data-id="'+ id + '"]').show();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution:

```
$('.row2').on('click', function(){
        $('.actionsDiv:visible').hide();

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('div[data-id="' + id + '"]').show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theagitator/5j7ymgxh/